# Why does [[no_unique_address]] have no effect on public data members?

Tags: c++, layout, c++20

Consider the following example:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    [[no_unique_address]] T t;
    int i;
};

struct B {
    long l;
    int i;
};

class C {
    long l;
    int i;
};
```

Both GCC and Clang think `sizeof(A<B>)` is `24`, while `sizeof(A<C>)` is `16`. [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Ed5bPPq1M)

Class template `A<T>` has `T` as one of its data members with the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute. The only difference between `B` and `C` is that `B` is a `struct` and `C` is a `class`. I can't understand why `A<B>` and `A<C>` are not the same size. In other words, why does the compiler embed member `i` of class template `A<T>` into the tail padding of `C` but not into the tail padding of `B`?

If I modify `B`'s member access to `private`, both GCC and Clang think the size of `A<B>` is `16`: ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4f9a8n9Mj))

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    [[no_unique_address]] T t;
    int i;
};

struct B {
private:      // private now
    long l;
    int i;
};

class C {
    long l;
    int i;
};
```

So it seems that the difference does not come from `struct` and `class`, but from the accessibility of data members.

I know it's implementation-defined whether the compiler embeds other members into the tail padding of members with the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute, but I guess there is some special rule that causes the same weird behavior in both GCC and Clang. I checked the standard and ABI documentation but couldn't find a description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of how layout is specified by the ABI.

https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#pod:

> The *dsize*, *nvsize*, and *nvalign* of these types are defined to be their ordinary size and alignment. These properties only matter for non-empty class types that are used as base classes. We ignore tail padding for PODs because the standard before the resolution of [CWG issue 43](https://wg21.link/CWG43) did not allow us to use it for anything else and because it sometimes permits faster copying of the type.

*dsize* is the "data size" of an object, which means how many bytes are used for the type, not including tail-padding.

This means that for "POD for the purpose of layout" types, the would-be tail-padding is considered part of the data of the type, so cannot be reused to hold the member `i` (the compiler sees `B` as an opaque 16 bytes, even though the last 4 bytes are padding)

When you make any member private, it is no longer "POD for the purpose of layout", so the *dsize* becomes `sizeof(long) + sizeof(int)` (instead of `sizeof(B) = 2 * sizeof(long)`), and the next member `i` *can* be placed in the tail-padding.

The same issue occurs if you try to make a base-class subobject.

```cpp
#if BASE_CLASS
template <class T>
struct A : T {
    int i;
};
#else
struct A {
    [[no_unique_address]] T t;
    int i;
};
#endif

struct B {
    long l;
    int i;
};  // dsize = 16, nvalign = 8, sizeof = 16

class C {
    long l;
    int i;
};  // dsize = 12, nvalign = 8, sizeof = 16 (next multiple of 8)

// A<B>: 16 bytes B, 4 bytes for int i, 4 bytes for padding
// dsize = 20, sizeof = 24

// A<C>: 12 bytes C, 4 bytes for int i, no padding
// dsize = 16, sizeof = 16

// (The same numbers for `[[no_unique_address]] T t;`)
```

---

CWG43 that is being referenced talks about how `memcpy` was specified to work on all POD types in C++98. So, a class laying out these types *must* include the tail-padding internally so that `memcpy` would not overwrite any data that would otherwise go into the padding. This was fixed in C++03 to specify "any object (other than a base-class subobject) of POD type `T`", but the layout rules were not changed (presumably so as to not break expectations that you could `memcpy` POD types, even if they were base classes).

`[[no_unique_address]]` was specified to have the same behaviour as a base class subobject (as a [*potentially-overlapping subobject*](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#definitions)), so this behaviour is inherited.